# Doctrine, symfony2 correct column type to use for calculating hours

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am recording peoples hours and minutes worked, and then adding them together to produce a total amount worked for a certain period. What is the best column type to use for this in Doctrine? My initial thought was just to use integer, but this will require back and forth conversion into Time formats.

What is the best practice for these sorts of time calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend either storing as an integer of minutes or as a custom "time" field that would automatically create a "Time" value object that would give you access to the methods that you need. The value object would be a bit more complicated.

The benefit of storing as minutes would be that you could do maths related searches (`SUM`, `AVG`, etc) directly rather than having to call each object individually and add them up that way.

On top of using the integer method you could create the same "Time" value object that took the time in minutes and then get that from your object like..

```
/**
 * Get minutes worked
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getMinutes()
{
    return $minutes;
}

/**
 * Set working minutes
 *
 * @param integer $minutes
 * @return $this
 */
public functions setMinutes($minutes)
{
    $this->minutes = $minutes

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get worked Time
 *
 * @return Time
 */
public function getTime()
{
    if (null === $this->minutes) {
        return $minutes;
        // Or return Time::fromMinutes(0);
    }

    return Time::fromMinutes($this->minutes);
}
```

And then in your value object..

```
class Time
{
    private $minutes;

    /**
     * Private constructor so as to use more meaningful static calls
     *
     * @param integer $minutes
     */
    private function __construct($minutes)
    {
        if ($is_int($minutes)) {
            throw new \Exception(sprintf(
                'Minutes expected to be an "integer", "%s" given',
                gettype($minutes)
            ));
        }

        $this->minutes = $minutes;
    }

    /**
     * Construct object from minutes
     *
     * @param integer $minutes
     * @return Time
     */
    public static function fromMinutes($minutes)
    {
        return self($minutes);
    }

    /**
     * Get time in minutes
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getMinutes()
    {
        return $this->minutes;
    }

    /**
     * Get time in hours and minutes string in 00:00 format
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAsString()
    {
        return sprintf(
            '%02d:%02d',
            floor($this->minutes / 60),
            $this->minutes % 60
        );
    }

    //...
    Any other methods
}
```

So your form could just take the minutes (or a 00:00 string with a data transformer) and then you could call it like `$job->getTime()->getAsString()` (after checking the time was not null, or alternatively returning an empty Time object).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, i will try this method as i will need to perform lots of math related searches.

Answer (score 1):

I think that for you case need to use "datetime" type filed. You can convert DateTime object in different formats

```
    /**
 * @var \DateTime $start
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $start;

/**
 * @var \DateTime $end
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
protected $end;

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getStart()
{
    return $this->start;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $start
 */
public function setStart(\DateTime $start)
{
    $this->start = $start;
}

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getEnd()
{
    return $this->end;
}

/**
 * @param \DateTime $end
 */
public function setEnd(\DateTime $end)
{
    $this->end = $end;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although rather then having the user select a time range they will just manually enter the Hours and Minutes worked. so the user input will just be something like 4:30 for 4 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: Calculating hours/minutes/seconds is easy once you have the `DateTime`, because you can substract the timestamps: `($date->getTimestamp() - $date2->getTimestamp()) / 60`.